# PhP - move_uploaded_file() nonsense

Tags: php

Code:

```
    echo $tmpName;
    echo "<br>". "{$uploadDir}/{$folderName}/{$fileName}";
    echo'<pre>';var_dump(file_exists("{$uploadDir}/{$folderName}"));echo'</pre>';
    echo'<pre>';var_dump(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, "{$uploadDir}/{$folderName}/{$fileName}"));echo'</pre>';
    echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms("{$uploadDir}/{$folderName}")), -4);     echo "<br>";


    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, "{$uploadDir}/{$folderName}/{$fileName}")) {
        $sqlup = "INSERT INTO upload_obrazky (slozka_upload_obrazky, pic_upload_obrazky) VALUES ('".$folderName."', '".$fileName."')";
        mysql_query( $sqlup );
        ++$counter;
    }
```

**Output:**

Tempname:

```
/tmp/phpH9a6xK
```

Real file & folders:

```
../files/upload/834e4315ebd644ac5bd0569af73a9cf1/akne.jpg
```

Folder exist?

```
bool(true)
```

Move uploaded file ??!!?!?!?!?!?!?!??!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!

```
bool(false)
```

Chmod on dir:

```
0777
```

---

Can someone tell me why is move_uploaded_file() **FALSE** ? Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you checked your logs?

Comment: You know you don't have to use braces (`{}`) around your variables like that.

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_exists($tmpName));` output?

Comment: There is output. Btw true

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to move the uploaded files twice

```
echo'<pre>';var_dump(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, "{$uploadDir}/{$folderName}/{$fileName}"));echo'</pre>';
```

And here:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, "{$uploadDir}/{$folderName}/{$fileName}")) {
```

Comment: i assume that was debugging and both block where not being run - but i could be wrong